# I am receiving "shmat: permission denied" when attempting to attach to shared memory. Why?

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

I'm having a little trouble with shared memory, and could use a little guidance if someone could point me in the right direction.

```
// Allocate Shared Memory
key_t key = 56789;
int shmid;
char* shm_address;
int* value;

// Reserve the memory
if (shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0777) < 0)
{
    perror("shmget was unsuccessful");
    exit(1);
}   
else
{
    printf("\nMemory created successfully:%d\n", shmid);
}

// Attach to memory address
if ( (shm_address = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (char *)-1 )
{

    perror("shmat was unsuccessful");
    exit(1);

}
else
{
    printf ("shared memory attached at address %p\n", shm_address);
}
```

I then do some process management, call `shmdt(shm_address)`, and finally cleanup with `shmctl`. But I never reach that part of the code.

I get this as output:

```
Memory created successfully:0

shmat was unsuccessful: Permission denied
```

I just don't understand why `shmat` is failing to attach? When I call the ipcs command after execution, my memory is allocated, so I'm fairly confident that `shmget` is working. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precedence error:

```
if (shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0777) < 0)
```

This assigns `shmget(key, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0777) < 0` (i.e. 0 or 1) to `shmid`. You want

```
if ((shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0777)) < 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, that moves me along. But I'm still receiving the same error, although the output has now changed to: memory created successfully: 501904483 shmat: permission denied

Comment: @NathanDarcy What happens if you `ipcrm` the segment and rerun your program?

Comment: I call the command ipcrm -m [seg_id], and the next call to ipcs shows that the memory is no longer listed. When I rerun the program, I'm left with the same results.

Comment: @NathanDarcy Well, that's bizarre. You're going to have to post a [mcve].

Comment: I'm baffled. I moved my exact code to a new location and it ran perfectly the first time. Maybe I somehow screwed up permissions for the original directory? Either way, thanks for the help.